# Models em Django fica tudo em um arquivo?

Tags: python-3.x, django

estou iniciando meus estudos em Django, venho de frameworks como Rails, Laravel, Asp.Net, e me deparei com uma diferença que até estranhei de no Django os models ficarem todos juntos, isso é normal? Tem uma forma de deixar cada model em um arquivo? A comunidade não estranha isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> É normal?

Depende de você. Para aplicações pequenas, geralmente não precisa de muitos arquivos, pode simplesmente juntar todos em um.

> Tem uma forma de deixar cada model em um arquivo?

Tem, mas você terá muito mais trabalho com isso, pois no Python o arquivo é que define um módulo. Criando um *model* em cada arquivo, você estará criando um módulo para cada *model*. Isso não faz sentido, além de adicionar uma redundância grande no código:

```
import foo.models.usuarios.Usuarios
import foo.models.cidades.Cidades
...
```

O nome do *model* acabará se repetindo como nome do módulo.

> A comunidade não estranha isso?

Não, pois essa é a filosofia do Python. Um diretório define um pacote (*package*) e um arquivo define um módulo (*module*). Muitas outras linguagens que citou não utilizam esse formato.

Mas, além de tudo, perceba que nem **todos** os *models* ficarão no mesmo arquivo. O Django trabalha com o conceito de *apps* e cada *app* possui seu próprio arquivo de *models*. Ou seja, apenas os *models* que estão relacionados e pertencem à um mesmo *app* que estarão no mesmo arquivo. Se sua aplicação crescer, acabará tendo vários *apps* e, consequentemente*, vários arquivos de *models*.